# Prove there is a subsequence of (Xn) s.t. for all k in N, (Xnk) >= k given (Xn) is unbounded above

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Question is as follows:

> Given that $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is unbounded above, prove that $\exists$ a subsequence $(X_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ of $(X_n)$ so that for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $X_{n_k} \geq k$.

I’m a little unsure on where to start. Initially I thought of employing the monotone subsequence theorem, but I’m not sure. Any hints?

Comment: Is that capital $K$ meant to be a lowercase $k$?

Comment: Yes just edited @XStanton

Comment: @Alex03 I suspect that you'll find it helpful to write out the precise definition of "unbounded above".

Comment: @XStanton Would this lead to a proof by contradiction?

Comment: Whoops, made a mistake. Refer to Ben Grossmann for the hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the sequence $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is unbounded above, we want to show that there exists a subsequence $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that for all $k\in \mathbb{N}, (X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\geq k$.

Base Case:
Since the sequence is unbounded above, there exists some $n_1$ such that $X_{n_1}\geq 1$

Inductive Step:
Assume that we have defined $n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_k$ such that $X_{n_j} \geq j$ for all $j=1,2,\ldots,k$. Now we need to find $n_{k+1}$ such that $X_{n_{k+1}} \geq k + 1$. Since the sequence is unbounded above, there exists some $n' \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $X_{n'} > k + 1$. We choose $n_{k+1}$ to be the smallest such $n' > n_k$ (to ensure the indices are increasing and thus we have a valid subsequence), so that $X_{n_{k+1}} \geq k + 1$.

This completes the inductive step and shows the existence of the subsequence $(X_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $X_{n_k} \geq k$.